# Python Memory Error

Tags: python, memory

I'm runing into Memory Error
Using python 2.6, pyodbc

The code loops through several Sql statements. Singleton run Ok, but the loops get stuck.
Sometimes Loop works ok.

```
for Sql in LoopList:
     f = csr.execute(Sql)
     LL = list(f)
```

The second element in loop crashes.

```
Sql:

Sql   =""" SELECT * FROM group WHERE 
        C>10 AND M <0 AND S<0  
        AND TC >= 200 AND OC >=1000  and Penny =.01 
        ORDER BY MSlp           
"""
```

Comment: LL crashes? what do you mean?

Comment: How much data is returned by the SQL statement? If it's hundreds of megabytes or larger, that's your problem right there.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a stack trace from the crash, told which platform you're running, what database you are using and other details that may help people identify or recognize the problem. The code you have is really so simple that I doubt it is simply a pyodbc error.

Comment: @joaguin, its hangs... or stops running error console Memory error.

Comment: how large is the result set? maybe too large for python to cope with?

Comment: How how long is the LoopList? How many iterations in are you crashing? Could you possibly be iterating over an infinite list?

Comment: @agf: the loop list has 8 elements, crashes after first. Not infinite list. Each element tested runs. when in loop list falis.

Comment: Maybe show us the exact code that works when run not in a loop?

Comment: When you test each query seperately do you also put the results into a list?

Comment: @Mark: yes. each into list then into new Sql table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do sql looplist inside MySQL  as Stored procedure, call from python. This eliminated the python error.

also use numpy for testing bytesize

Answer (score 4):

Your query is returning too much data to fit into memory. The `execute` is probably returning an iterator which only needs to keep one item in memory at a time, but converting that into a `list` requires every single item returned from the query to fit into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is returning too much data that it cannot be stored in RAM, for a quick solution try increasing your virtual memory.

1. Open My Computer
2. Right click and select Properties
3. Go to Advanced System Settings
4. Click on Advance Tab
5. [Click on settings under Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChcZa.png)
6. [Click on Change under Advance Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwFES.png)
7. Increase the memory size, that will increase virtual memory size.

It will convert some of your hard disk space to virtual memory, and your issue will be resolved now if your data fits into allocated memory.